# What's wrong with this argument about fractional exponents?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs, paradoxes

I am sure that this has been discussed many times and the answer may be trivial. But I was confronted with the following issue and could not give a satisfactory answer:
$$1=(-1^{6})^{\frac{1}{2}}=-1^{6\cdot\frac{1}{2}} = -1^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot 6}=(-1^{\frac{1}{2}})^6 = (\sqrt{-1})^6.$$

On the left handside of the chain, we have $1$, and on the right handside, we have the square root of a negative number, which is not defined with real numbers. Also moving towards complex numbers does not seem to help, as 
$$(\sqrt{-1})^6 = (\sqrt{i^2})^6 = i^6 = (i^2)^3 = (-1)^3 = -1.$$
Where is the mistake or the step that is not allowed?

Comment: Left-hand side, not "left handside"

Comment: $(x^{a})^b \ne x^{ab}$, in general unless $x\ge0$

Comment: Dr. MV, is that a general convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whomever presented the "proof" was not rigorous in their argument and skipped a step:

$$1 = (-1)^3 = ((-1)^6)^{\frac {1}{2}}= ... $$

That skipped step is false.